# How can we install devtoolset-4.0 on CentOS 6.7

Tags: centos, gcc, g++

I tried to install devtoolset-4.0 to use g++ version 5.x via

```
sudo yum install devtoolset-4
```

However, I got **No package devtoolset-4 available.**

Is there any way to get to that?

Comment: If you just want g++ and its dependencies: After adding the SCL repos as in @13nilux's answer, you may want to install `devtoolset-4-toolchain` (22 packages including binutils and gcc-c++) rather than `devtoolset-4` (278 packages including the toolchain plus eclipse and many other java tools).

Answer (score 7):

Install it by:

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install devtoolset-4
```

The first command installs and enables `Software Collections Repository` on your CentOS machine. That repository provides the `devtoolset` package.

Answer (score 2):

This does not work on CentOS 6.10 anymore.

Those are the ones available without jumping through hoops:

```
[misp@misp-centos6 ~]$ yum search devtoolset |grep devtoolset|awk {'print $1'} |cut -f 1,2 -d\-|sort|uniq
===========================
devtoolset-6
devtoolset-6.x86_64
devtoolset-7
devtoolset-7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the testing repository:

```
sudo yum -y install centos-release-scl
sudo yum-config-manager --enable centos-sclo-rh-testing
sudo yum install devtoolset-4-toolchain
```

devtoolset-4-toolchain installs relevant packages for c++. devtoolset-3 is broken on Centos6, it is available from Scientific Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I was creating Dockerfile for old CentOS 6.8 with g++ 5.2.1. Here is what worked:

```
# yum install -y centos-release-scl-rh \
&& DTS4_PACKAGES="devtoolset-4-gcc-5.2.1 devtoolset-4-gcc-c++-5.2.1 devtoolset-4-gdb" \
&& yum -y install --enablerepo=centos-sclo-rh-testing --setopt=tsflags=nodocs $DTS4_PACKAGES \
&& yum -y clean all --enablerepo='*' \
&& export PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/bin:$PATH
```

and using `install devtoolset-4` would install the whole lot, including eclipse.

Some packages are available on vault.centos.org, but not on mirror.centos.org and they can be loaded with `yum-utils` and `yumdownloader`.

More info:

[centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-sclo-rh-testing-x86_64/devtoolset-4-gcc-5.2.1-2.2.el6.x86_64.rpm](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-sclo-rh-testing-x86_64/devtoolset-4-gcc-5.2.1-2.2.el6.x86_64.rpm.html)
https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-install-an-rpm-file-in-linux/
http://vault.centos.org/centos/6.8/sclo/x86_64/rh/devtoolset-4/